# How to install php5-gd on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, php5-gd

I'm running ubuntu 10.04.

I just ran the command,

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

but it gave me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-gd: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4) but 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

When tried an apt-get install on php5-common, but it says i already have the most recent version.  How do i install php5-gd?

**Additional Info**
Here's what I see after doing a `sudo apt-get update | grep main`

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable/main Packages [1,093B]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main Packages [737B]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update package index files(current [php5-common](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/lucid/php5-common) 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Check follow string in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
```

Fix:

```
$ sudo -s
# echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get install php5-gd
```

Comment: the update went fine, still getting the same error with installing php5-gd.

Comment: @John add output "apt-get update | grep main"

Comment: ok, I did it and appended the output to the Additional Info in my question.  Thanks ooshro!

Comment: @John You need add lucid-security and lucid-updates repository

Comment: Make sure you restart apache server. Worked for me only then.

Answer (score 0):

you probably just forgot to do `sudo apt-get update`

if that doesnt work for you try `sudo apt-get update && apt-get -f install`

if that doesnt work either you probably messed  up your sources of something

last ultima ratio which is not recommended is to force it by something like `dpkg -i --force-depends-version` but you should rather try to fix the issue.

without more information i unfortunately cant help you any further.

Comment: i tried running both sudo apt-get update lines which worked, but still getting the same error with the php5-gd.  I'm not sure how to use the dpkg command....is it used in conjunction with the sudo apt-get install php5-gd command?